# "UIObjects" on one side of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, transform

I'm working on an application, in which I use some 'transformations'. First, I have declared a 'UIView' like this :

```
viewTest = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 220, 380)];
viewTest.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:viewTest];
```

I know how to add some elements like 'UIButton' or other things like that on this view. But what i want is, to put them on one side side of the 'UIView'. Because i make some transformations like this :

```
viewTest.layer.transform = aRotation;
```

and i want that after a rotation, the other side of the 'UIView' don't get any objects. I mean, I see 'UIView' like a wall where you could put some elements on the two sides, "exterior and interior"…

Thanks !

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: How could I declared some UIObjects to be only on one side of a UIView ? So after a rotation of the UIView, a UIButton would not be visible for example. As in a game card, if you turn a card, the other side is different...

Answer (score 0):

You can add views to a view as subviews even if their frames are outside the bounds of their superview. Just make sure you set

```
viewTest.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

.

Comment: But i don't have problems with dimensions, i have problem with the fact that i want to put for example to different 'UIImageview' on two sides of a UIView. As in a game card for example.

Comment: I don't see the problem. You either add subviews to a view smaller than the bounds, or to another one that comprises all of the subviews. You can put anything on there, images, text etc. Then you can rotate or otherwise transform the whole superview.

Comment: Yes you said it : "You can put anything on there", and "Then you can rotate". But after a rotation of 180° of the UIView, is it possible to put some different objects on the other side of the UIView ? As in a game card, if you return a card, the other side is different

Comment: The trick is to rotate 90°, then in the completion handler change the image or other content and then do the second 90° of the rotation.